# Angular 6 - rxjs pipe not working on valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

I have a reactive form, with a text input. For ease of access in my typescript, I declared:

```
get parentId(): FormControl {
    return this.addForm.get("parentId") as FormControl;
}
```

This part works, the control is properly accessed.

Now in my ngOnInit if I do this:

```
this.parentId.valueChanges.subscribe(() => console.log("Changed"));
```

The console log is executed at every character changed in the input, as expected. But if I do this:

```
this.parentId.valueChanges.pipe(tap(() => console.log("Changed")));
```

Nothing happens. No errors, no anything. I tried also using map, switchMap, etc.nothing works. It seems that the pipe does not work on valueChanges. I am using the pipe method elsewhere in my code on different observables without any problem.

And I need to use pipe here in order to debounce, map, etc.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

-- Edit --

This is the code example from Angular Material site, on Autocomplete component:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
       .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(val => this.filter(val))
       );
}
```

There is no subscribe at the end and the example works.

Comment: Observables won't emit anything until you subscribe to them. So if you want to see output from `tap` you need to call `subscribe()` after `pipe()`.

Comment: You need a `subscribe()` at the end of the chain to activate the observable.

Comment: In the example on Angular Material site on autocomplete component there is no such thing:

Comment: You're both right. There is no subscribe in the example because the pipe is bound to a variable which is "subscribed to" with the async pipe. My fault for not understanding that. Thanks.

Comment: @martin Just came here looking for the same problem, thanks very much!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to activate the `Observable`,

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
       .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(val => this.filter(val))
       ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: So simple, yet so accurate. Thanks. I'm still struggling to wrap my head around observables and their differences from promises.

Comment: You can use the pipe async at your template too. 

*ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"

Comment: Getting this error when add .subcription
`TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<string[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.`

I assign like this `filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;`